# Config server not getting discovered in a consul first setup

Tags: spring-cloud, service-discovery, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

I am using a consul first setup. For this ,I am using a consul docker image with port 8500 mapped to 8500 so I can successfully use it on local set up.I can access consul at http://localhost:8500 .

I have the following configuration for the **config server -**
**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.RC1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Application.yml**

```
server:
   port: 8888
spring:
   cloud:
     config:
       server:
         git:
           uri: https://github.com/xxxxxx/spring-config-repo.git
consul:
  host: consul
  port: 8500
  enabled: true
  discovery:
    enabled: true
    register: true
    service-name: configservice
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
   application:
     name: config-server
```

**ConfigServerApplication.java**

```
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run this jar, it is successful. I can see the config server in consul ui.
Following are the details of the config server as seen from consul-

```
Request - http://localhost:8500/v1/catalog/services
Response - 
{
"configservice": [],
"consul": []
}

Request - http://localhost:8500/v1/catalog/service/configservice
Response - 
[
 {
    "ID": "f6ac953c-07b9-4097-974e-3ea9cd39bec2",
    "Node": "a0954c644062",
    "Address": "127.0.0.1",
    "TaggedAddresses": {
        "lan": "127.0.0.1",
        "wan": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "NodeMeta": {},
    "ServiceID": "config-server-8888",
    "ServiceName": "configservice",
    "ServiceTags": [],
    "ServiceAddress": "10.0.0.158",
    "ServicePort": 8888,
    "ServiceEnableTagOverride": false,
    "CreateIndex": 15,
    "ModifyIndex": 15
 }
]
```

I can also access the config server using this uri-

```
http://localhost:8888/configclient/default
```

I have client application which uses properties from the config server.My understanding is that when I run this jar, it will contact consul and get the config server information from there and populate the properties by fetching it from the given git uri.

Following are the details about the client -
**pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.RC1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
   application:
      name: myservice
cloud:
  config:
    fail-fast: true
    retry:
      max-attempts: 20
      initial-interval: 3000
   enabled: true
   discovery:
     enabled: true
     service-id: configserver
consul:
  host: localhost
  port: 8500
  discovery:
    enabled: true
    register: true
    service-name: myservice
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
   port: 8081
```

**MyServiceApplication.java**

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplePaymentServiceApplication.class,    args);
    }
}
```

But during this startup of this jar, its not able to find the config server and instead falls back on the default uri .
This is the relevant startup log section

```
2017-03-28 00:40:20.407  WARN 99123 --- [           main]  lientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration : No instances found of  configserver (configserver)


2017-03-28 00:40:20.551  INFO 99123 --- [           main]  b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source:   CompositePropertySource [name='consul', propertySources= . [ConsulPropertySource [name='config/myservice/'],   ConsulPropertySource [name='config/application/']]]
2017-03-28 00:40:20.587  INFO 99123 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2017-03-28 00:40:21.831  INFO 99123 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=myservice, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
2017-03-28 00:40:21.832  INFO 99123 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='https://github.com/xxxxx/spring-config-repo.git/myservice.yml'], MapPropertySource [name='https://github.com/xxxxx/spring-config-repo.git/application.yml']]]
2017-03-28 00:40:21.841  INFO 99123 --- [           main] c.h.MyServiceApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

I tinkered with a lot of different options from various examples such as 
    [consul first bootstrap with spring cloud config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629943/consul-first-bootstrap-with-spring-cloud-config)

Can someone point to what I might be missing ?
Any pointers to a working example with access to proper application/bootstrap files for consul, configserver and client would be most helpful .

PS: I apologize for the information overload in the question. Some of it might not be relevant but I wanted to give as much information as possible so that someone can spot something that they have encountered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to look up `configserver`, but it is registered as `configservice`.

Comment: Thanks spencer. I think I did quite a bit of tinkering and some how was left with that mismatch is names and didn't even notice that. I works fine now.

Comment: I think I have. I think toggling the check mark to green does it.i did it the first thing after the solution worked.:)Anything else I have to do apart from that ?

Comment: I have no idea what "toggling the check mark to green" means. What check box and where?